# how to avoid the deployment filename in the endpoint url in jboss EAP

Tags: jboss, endpoint

We have multiple war files deployed on JBoss server, if I am not setting the below property in the jboss-web.xml, it is by default including the war filename in the endpoint url :

```
<context-root>/</context-root>
```

but I cannot do this for all war files since they are all different projects (each has its own jboss-web.xml). It gives the duplicate exception if I do so..

```
JBWS022102: Cannot stop endpoint in state UNDEFINED: jboss.ws:context=*****

ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."*************-webservices-1_0.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."*************-webservices-1_0.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "*************-webservices-1_0.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:189)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
```

How to avoid the war filename in this case?

Comment: How do you build your WAR's? With Maven?

Comment: yes... we are using maven.. we have more than 1 WAR file

Answer (score 1):

By default WildFly use the name of the deployment as the deployments context name. As you noted, you can use a `jboss-web.xml` to override this. You can't deploy multiple applications with the same context so using `<context-root>/</context-root>` will not work.

Each deployment will need it's own context name. It's best to use a known name. You could use contexts like `/api`, `/webservices`, `/web` etc. You could also use the name of the project without the version name.

You could hard-code like:

```xml
<context-root>/webservices</context-root>
```

With a different `context-root` for each deployment. This could be automated with Maven by using filtering of the `jboss-web.xml` resource and an entry like:

```xml
<context-root>/${project.artifactId}</context-root>
```

Another option is to use the `<finalName>` configuration parameter in your `<build>` section of your POM.

```xml
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    ....
</build>
```

The final option is to override the runtime name at deployment time. This depends on how you deploy your application.

With CLI:

```
/deployment=webservices:add(content=[{url=file:///path/to/webservies-1.0.war}], runtime-name=webservices.war)
/deployment=webservices:deploy
```

With the [WildFly Maven Plugin](https://docs.wildfly.org/wildfly-maven-plugin):

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.plugin.wildfly}</version>
    <configuration>
        <runtime-name>webservices.war</runtime-name>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If you deploy through the web console you should see ways to override the runtime name.

Comment: Thank you - this solution works with the JBoss.. but we have those old end points which we are trying to avoid renaming or changing since they are already configured at our gateway. I was just looking for a solution for this

Comment: You can't have more than on deployment on the same context. The container would have no idea where to route it.

Comment: I found a unique string for each webservice so all good here - thanks..